# Appending data-attribute to list of elements from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I'm trying to make a custom navigation to slick a slider with buttons that will extend the functionality of the original navigation dots.

All I need to do is get a data attribute 'data-slick-index' from every fourth slide in the slider and append it to the same number of  elements that already exist in my HTML (they are generated from the back-end).

I managed to collect all of the data attributes of every slide that I need with this piece of code:

```
var tableSlideIndexes = [];
$(currentSlider).find('.slick-slide:nth-child(3n - 2)').each(function() {
    var indexedSlide = $(this);
    tableSlideIndexes.push([ indexedSlide.data('slick-index') ]);
});
```

But now I have no idea how to append the data from the tableSlideIndexes array to each  element with the same data attribute.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Share your HTML

Comment: *But now don't have an idea how to append the data from the array tableSlideIndexes to all elements like the same data attribute.* What?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a0ythxoc/1/

Consider every .body-column div like separate slide.

Comment: @AllChannels: question is not clear.

Comment: Sorry, will try to make it more comprehensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
$(currentSlider).parents('.big-table').prev('.quarters-navigation').find('.year-nav').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('data-slick-index', tableSlideIndexes[i]);
});
```

It's very basic `jQuery` function.
Now I know what connexo meant.

Thank you all.